# Queue broker that implements a queue of queues

Tags: java, rabbitmq, queue, message-queue

I'm looking to use a queue broker for my use case but am having trouble finding one that could suit my needs. Perhaps my needs are uncommon or I am going about the wrong way of solving my problem.

The situation: Millions of messages of person demographics data come in to the system. Each of these messages has identifiers that are unique to that person. Unfortunately, the sending systems vary widely and some have odd practices that result in dozens, even occasionally hundreds, of the same person coming in to the system within small time frame. Our current queueing system has multiple processors with no awareness of these people and their identifiers, it's basically a bucket pull and process in a time-based fashion. As such, we could end up processing the same person at the same time, resulting in contention and race conditions. Ultimately it's not a data problem because of database transaction rollbacks, but it's obviously a lot of unneeded processing (since the failed transaction results in the message getting requeued). Because of downstream actions and our lack of sending system knowledge, though, we can't really ignore or drop certain messages -- we have to eventually process them all.

My ideal solution would be a queue of queues, based on the unique identifier each person has. So, the way it would work is there would be a master queue which is continually getting processed. Each time a unique person comes in to the system, a new queue for that identifier is created. If that person comes in again, the message gets added to that unique identifier queue. So, when the master queue finally dequeues that element, it works through that unique identifier queue in order. Since the work of each unique identifier queue would be in a separate thread, the master queue could continue dispatching elements (up to some arbitary limit of the number of uniqueue identifier queue worker threads). This allows for processing of many messages without having the same person being worked on by different processes.

I've looked extensively into RabbitMQ and see nothing that would allow for behavior approaching this. Even if I were to make a new queue for each unique identifier, I don't see a way that they could be processed in an orderly fashion. And the overhead alone on creating millions of queues would be pretty extreme.

I've only briefly looked at other queueing brokers but googling for the concept of a queue of queues doesn't return much useful information, so I'm beginning to think this is a problem that people don't need to solve.  So, my question is, is there an a solution out there that would facilitate a queue of queues in a similar fashion to what I've described? If not, is there a better or different way of handling this?

Comment: Not sure if relevant but have you looked at [Javaspecialists #206 Striped Executor Service](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue206.html)?

Comment: It's not clear how your queues are currently being used. Are you processing one type of function per queue?

Comment: @theMayer Our current queue processor just pulls a bucket of events (say 200) and processes them. There are multiple queue processors. I don't know that really matters since we want to improve on the current queue processing, not exactly replicate it. With the way it is now, it's very easy for duplicate unique identifier people to be processed by different processors at the same time, hence wanting to have a queue of queues.

Comment: Well, I have found it to be particularly useful to organize queues to process exactly one type of thing (e.g. a single event type). If you have more than one type of thing, you need more than one queue as a general rule. You are correct that RabbitMQ does not implement advanced partitioning based on properties of items in the queue. This really would be better done in a tool meant for that, such as a database.

Comment: @AHungerArtist Since I have a similar problem as you had once year ago, I was wondering how (and if!) you solved it. Would you mind to share your experiences here?

Comment: @GoloRoden I've yet to solve it but had to move on to other things. If you should happen to figure out a solution, please come back here and provide some insight.